# What's the output of following program which shows the unusual output and why?

Tags: c

[see the ouput image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX1w8.png)

What's the output of following code and why?

I am curious to know why c compiler shows the unusual output.

What happens behind the scene?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a,b,c;

    printf("Enter First char:");
    scanf("%c",&a);

    printf("Enter Second char:");
    scanf("%c",&b);

    printf("Enter Third char:");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    return 1;
}


Enter First char:a
Enter Second char:Enter Third char:c
```

see above output, its not taking 2nd input and directly asking third one!

Comment: `// what's the output of following code and why ?`...did you atleast try running and understanding the output?

Comment: Well, what **is** the output? Run it and tell us (end especially tell us what confuses you about it)

Comment: What output do you expect and what output do you get, please edit your question and make that clear.

Comment: My guess it's about [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer).

Comment: Is it about output of the program or "unusal output" of the compiler? Please be more precise.

Comment: Enter First char:a
Enter Second char:Enter Third char:c

it shows the above output. i am not getting why?

Comment: @VikasRathod please [edit] your question and put clarifications _there_.

Comment: ... as *text* not image please. You can read the duplicate question linked for an explanation and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/4142924).

Comment: Basic debug (printing a, b and c) would have answered this question before it was even posted...  Possible duplicate of [scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you type `1` and hit `Enter` (`Enter` is interpreted as newline character)

The first scanf reads `'1'`.

The second scanf reads `'\n'`.

Then you type `2` and click `Enter`.  The third scanf reads `'2'`.

Probably you need to read `"%c "` or `" %c"`, since `' '` in format string skips all whitespaces.

Comment: The trailing space in `"%c "` is not advised, the leading space is good.